# spring boot multiple mongodb datasource

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

We are using spring boot and we have multiple mongodbs within the system. We are able to configure "one" mongodb in application.properties files, as per the spring boot documents. Now we have a need to write to multiple mongodbs. How can we configure this?

Hope someone can help and any code examples would be helpful.

Thanks
GM

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple @Bean methods, where you create and configure your datasources, and specify the bean name to distinguish them.

Example:

```
@Bean("primary")
public Mongo primaryMongo() throws UnknownHostException {
    Mongo mongo = new Mongo();

    // configure the client ...

    return mongo;
}

@Bean("secondary")
public Mongo secondaryMongo() throws UnknownHostException {
    Mongo mongo = new Mongo();

    // configure the client ...

    return mongo;
}
```

When you want to access the datasource, use the @Qualifier annotation on the field to specify the datasource with the bean name:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("primary")
private Mongo mongo;
```